После переустановки пакета gdm3 и ubuntu-desktop, система не может запуститься
Недавно я пытался исправить проблему с драйверами для наушников и следовал инструкции по этому ответу на askubuntu. К слову версия ubuntu у меня самая последняя установил её чуть больше месяца назад 24.04 LTS, регулярно обновлялся. Сначала удалил и переустановил пакеты ALSA. Потом я переустановил пакеты gdm3 и ubuntu desktop (или удалил, не помню, в этом то и дело). И после следующего запуска ПК происходит следующее: я включаю пк, выбираю ubuntu, и меня закидывает в чёрный экран где нужно ввести админский логин и пароль, высвечивается эта надпись и через долю секунды она пропадает и снова просят админский логин с паролем. Что мне делать? Как восстановить данные? Возможно ли восстановить систему в то положение в котором она была до этого случая?

Ну а если ввести логин и пароль - чё будет?
